# Grails 2.1.0 domain class boolean default value of false

Tags: grails, dns, boolean

I have the following within my domain

```
boolean checkbox1
boolean checkbox2
boolean checkbox3

static constraints {
       checkbox1(blank: true, nullable: true)
}
```

now when I save, in my view I've got no value set to checkbox1 and I'm getting the following error:

> - Field error in object 'com.smstool.myDomain' on field 'checkbox1': rejected value [false]; codes
>     [typeMismatch.com.myApp.myDomain.checkbox1,typeMismatch.checkbox1,typeMismatch.boolean,typeMismatch]

my view is:

```
<g:checkBox name="${domainReference}checkbox1" value="${thisInstance?.checkbox1}" class="myCheckbox"  />
```

I can't figure out why this is happening? surely if I've got blank: true and nullable: true then this should ignore the mismatch?

Answer (score 1):

The issue is the primitive `boolean` can not be `null`. If you need `null` then use `Boolean` not `boolean`.

Also, `blank` will have no effect here since that's only for `Strings`.